# How do I sort a SQL Server 2008 pivot result columns and rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I'm using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) to get pivot results for a table. But I want the resulting columns and rows both in a specific order. So the rows would be sorted by `CDATE` and the columns would be `CDATE`, `BALANCE`, then the `DATE` columns.

```
CDATE      | BALANCE | 04-2007 | 05-2007 | 06-2007 | TRANS TOT
2003-01-15 | 5000    | 60      | 0       | 0       | 60 
2003-02-15 | 4000    | 40      | 0       | 0       | 40
2003-03-15 | 5500    | 20      | 15      | 15      | 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the answer in the link you provided in your question to achieve the ordering issue. Just add `ORDER BY` clause to your dynamic query:

```
create table temp
(
    date datetime,
    category varchar(3),
    amount money
)

insert into temp values ('1/1/2012', 'ABC', 1000.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'DEF', 500.00)
insert into temp values ('2/1/2012', 'GHI', 800.00)
insert into temp values ('2/10/2012', 'DEF', 700.00)
insert into temp values ('3/1/2012', 'ABC', 1100.00)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.category) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p  ORDER BY date, ' + @cols 


Execute(@query)

drop table temp
```

OR You can use [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to achieve this. like the following:

```
set @query = 'WITH CTE_1(date, ' + @cols + ') AS (SELECT date, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select date
                    , amount
                    , category
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(amount)
                for category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ) SELECT * FROM CTE_1 ORDER BY date, ' + @cols
```